# How to "completely" hide all animator controls in Manipulate[]

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

The following generates a `Manipulate[]` with an animator that is controlled with a slider and buttons.

```
Manipulate[Graphics[], {a, 1, 4}, ControlType -> Animator, AppearanceElements -> None]
```

I do not want the buttons at all and I don't want to lose any space where the controls would have been.  The look I want is given by

```
Manipulate[Graphics[], {a, 1, 4}, ControlType -> None, 
 AppearanceElements -> None]
```

Notice there are no sliders, buttons or appearance elements and no lose space.  Just a blank frame.

My issue is that I want the control type to be animator and I can't seem to get the desired look.  Is it possible to retain animator as the control type but without any buttons or slider at all while not displaying any wasted space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Manipulate

```
Manipulate[Graphics[Text[Style[Round[a] , RandomInteger[{46, 120}], Hue[RandomReal[]]]], 
      ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
   {{a, 1, ""}, 1, 10, ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> 5, 
      AnimationRunning -> True, AppearanceElements -> {}}, 
   AppearanceElements -> {}, Paneled -> False] //
 Panel[#, FrameMargins -> {{0, 0}, {-10, -40}}] &
```

[image]

### Clock

```
repeats = 20; 
Dynamic @ Panel @ Graphics[Text[Style[Round[Clock[{0, 1, .1}, 1, repeats]], 
  RandomInteger[{46, 120}], Hue[RandomReal[]]]], 
 ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is this `Panel` wrapper OS independent?

Comment: @Kuba, it works in version 9.0 windows 10 and in version 11.2 on wolfram cloud.

Comment: I was thinking about mac/win because it is often a pain to adjust those values between them. Will check that next week, unless I forget.

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier with explicit `Animator` and `Overlay`. You can use it within `Manipulate` too but here there is no reason to keep it so I will change it to `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[ 
  {a}
, Panel @ Overlay[
    { Animator[Dynamic[a], {1, 4}, AppearanceElements -> None]
    , Panel @ Graphics[Inset @ Dynamic @ a]
    }
  , All
  , 2
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I see.  I was hoping there was a simple answer with Manipulate.   If I click on the little "+" button in appearance elements and click "Hide Controls" it does what is needed.  I'm surprised isn't a simple option for that in the controls.